# Change button position by clicking event?

Tags: javascript, html, css

There is button is on the left side of its container, with the text Go Right!.
When the button is on the left side, clicking it results in the button moving to the right side of the container.
When the button is on the right side, the button text is Go Left!
When the button is on the right side, clicking it results in the button moving to the left side of the container.

I tried this:
html:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <button id="flip-flop" onclick="moveRight()">Go Right!</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

js file:

```
function moveRight(){
    const flip_flip_button = document.getElementById("flip-flop")
    flip_flip_button.addEventListener("click", function () {
       flip_flip_button.style.left = 400 + "px";
    });
}
```

css:

```
.container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: gray;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#flip-flop{
    position: relative;
}
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fqbvu.png)

This code result, the button is move right (by second click? don't know why also) but not responsive.How can I  move right button just until container right side?

Comment: Please create a fiddle link and share?

Comment: You are adding a click listener **every time** the button is clicked.

Comment: How long the button is will determine where it is in the container.

Answer (score 2):

Several problems here.

1. You are adding a click listener every time the button gets clicked. Instead, only add one listener, that does the actual work you want.
2. Don't work with `element.style`, as that produces inline styles, which are widely consider very bad practice. Instead, prepare a CSS class in your CSS that contains the desired styles, and toggle that class on click.
3. In this case the easiest way to get your button aligned to the right is setting `text-align: right` on the button's parent element.

```js
document
  .getElementById('flip-flop')
  .addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.parentNode.classList.toggle('right');
  });
```

```css
.container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: gray;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#flip-flop {
  position: relative;
}

.right {
  text-align: right;
}

#flip-flop::after {
  content: " right!";
}

.right #flip-flop::after {
  content: " left!";
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button id="flip-flop">Go</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This example doesn't show how to Go Left once the button reaches the end of the container.

Comment: Added that, along with changing the button text.